# Алгоритм смены слайдов в карусели

Tags: алгоритм

хочу разобраться. Не могу придумать как сделать слайдер на js. Исходные данные:

1. n-ое кол-во фото (известно)
2. кол-во отображаемых фото (известно) ширина вычисляется(т.е. известна).
3. прокрутка кнопками и при нажатии на точки под слайдером(1ая точка соответствует изначальной первой картинке в ряду).
   Все делаю через смещение (translateX). При прокрутке кнопками все хорошо(дохожу до конца и клонирую фото с начала, точки внизу бегают правильно), при перемещении по точкам все тоже правильно бегает (реализация: дохожу до конца ряда фото и клонирую с начала количество-1 отображаемых фото).

Проблема в том что если я перемещался при помощи точек, а потом перешел на кнопки иногда происходит сбой(реализация: проверяю длину списка фото и позицию фото в данный момент и если позиция меньше коль-ва первоночального списка фото, то удаляю с конца лишние и все опять работает сначала, а если позиция на последних(добавленных временно фото) то тут получается очень громоздкая проверка и код).
Как можно реализовать зацикленный слайдер чтобы не было глюков в описанных случаях. Или как вообще лучше делать? В нете много инфы, но везде по отдельности, нету всего и сразу чтобы подсмотреть реализацию.
p.s. надеюсь понятно написал. Мне не надо код, а именно сам алгоритм.
**Как можно реализовать зацикленный слайдер чтобы переход осуществлялся и кнопками и сразу в любое место по точкам внизу.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

можете реализовать его как [тут](http://o978717t.beget.tech/)(точки специально отключены для десктопа) , для этого есть готовый инструмент [Slick.js](https://realadmin.ru/saytostroy/slick-slider.html)

```
 // если ещё не подключен jQuery
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<div class="slider single-item">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>

    $('.multiple-items').slick({
      infinite: true,
      dots: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
```

Comment: спасибо. Готовых решений много. В вашем примере нету одновременно и того и другого. Я делаю просто для себя, изучаю js.  По-этому мне важен просто алгоритм, думал может есть какой-то неофициально утвержденный.

Comment: в примере можно включить одновременно и стрелки и точки. Я немного позже дополню ответ общим алгоритмом реализации.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду ждать.